# Different response format depending on get parameter

Tags: rest, parameters, request, format, response

A have an entity, but i need to represent it in two really different ways. Now filters seems different too, but i think of future and don't want to duplicate endpoints from the start. So i think of one endpoint.

But it seems very unclear to api client, isn't?

For example, request for user/partners should give one data response, and user/partners?custom=true gives another response data. I mean not different attributes, that can be done with query for 'fields=attribute1,attribute2'. I mean they have different entity format, that can have same or different attributes with same or different format of representation. For example, attributes username for first request can return simply login, but for second request return array of subattributes.

So is it good idea to have such different response formats in one endpoint or should i separate them from the start?

Answer (score 0):

> So is it good idea to have such different response formats in one endpoint or should i separate them from the start?

General purpose HTTP clients don't care about "endpoints".

```
/abcde
/abcde?format=text
/abcde?format=json
```

As far as a general purpose client is concerned, these are *different* identifiers, that are used to look up *different* resources (aka "documents").

Whether or not requests for these resources is handled by the same "endpoint" is just an implementation detail.  From the outside, it makes no difference whether each resource has its own endpoint, or if some resources share an endpoint, or if all resources use the same endpoint.

What that means is that judgment of whether or not sharing an endpoint is a good idea depends on balancing other factors

- which spelling produces higher internal code quality (which is going to depend somewhat on the idioms used by your routing framework)
- which spelling is more convenient for human operators reviewing the access logs
- which spelling is more amenable to documentation

The right answer in the human interfaces is likely to be dependent on how these resources fit into the domain (are the really variations of a common document? or are they different documents that just happen to be derived from a common data set?).

Comment: Thank you for answer. These entities is the same model in application. But in one case it represents entity by original attributes, but another is represented by customizable attributes, that authorized user can configure by himself, but just turn each on or off. What do you recommend now?

Comment: I think of separate endpoints now, because of different set of get parameters, that can apply each resource. I mean one resource can handle one set of parameters, but second resource can't handle them and have his own set of attributes. Yes, they will have same parameters of course, but going further it can be complicated to document and work with one common resource with conflicts. What do you think? Help me please. Am i right?